# Sending an email to multiple recipients via a mail relay, while hiding the recipients

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, email-server, exchange-2007

Our software sends emails using Exchange. Typically each email foes to multiple recipients and we just send one email with multiple "to" addresses.

We're moving to an SMTP-based email relay, where we send the email to an Exchange server, and it relays the email on. One thing we want is that each recipient should not know the recipient-list, and at the moment we plan to simply put all recipients in the email "bcc" list. But it seems like this might be a really common issue that Exchange (and other relay software) might handle in a better way.

Can anyone tell me if there is a 'right way' to do this, and any technical terms I need to know?

We prefer not to send the email multiple times from our software.

Comment: AFAIK the BCC header is to only way to go. Your application sends a single message and the first SMTP server  will expand the headers including the BCC header, which either gets [stripped or removed](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.3) from the message, and route a unique copy of the original for each of the individual  intended recipients as found on the To:, CC: and BCC: lines.

Comment: `But it seems like this might be a really common issue that Exchange (and other relay software) might handle in a better way` - BCC provides exactly the functionality you describe, so why would there be a better way? `Can anyone tell me if there is a 'right way' to do this` - Yes, use BCC. I hate to state the obvious, but BCC does what you're looking for so I don't know why you'd feel compelled to find another method. Why don't you just use the functionality that BCC provides? Don't overthink this.

Answer (score 1):

`BCC` is designed for the functionality you are asking.  Change your scripts to use `BCC` instead of `TO`